# Prevent assetic from sending css files to compass

Tags: symfony, assetic, compass

I'm working on a symfony 2.8 project.
Assetic is used to combine CSS to one file. I have written my own CSS as SCSS an use compass to compile it.

I now added a 3. party lightbox plugin and can't get assetic to put my SCSS and the plain CSS of the lightbox together.

Assetic config:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        compass:
            bin: /usr/local/bin/compass
            apply_to: '\.scss$'
```

HTML-Head:

```
{% stylesheets
        'css/screen.scss'
        'assets/vendor/lightgallery/dist/css/lightgallery.css'
        filter='cssrewrite,compass' output='css/compiled/app.css' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

With this I get an error like:

```
    /*
    [exception] 500 | Internal Server Error | Assetic\Exception\FilterException
    [message] An error occurred while running:
    '/usr/local/bin/ruby' '/usr/local/bin/compass' 'compile' '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/XYZ/app/cache/dev' '--boring' '--images-dir' '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/XYZ/app/../web/images' '--config' '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/XYZ/app/cache/dev/assetic_compass05Ld1V' '--sass-dir' '' '--css-dir' '' '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/XYZ/app/cache/dev/assetic_compassRm5H7y.css'

    Error Output:
    WARNING on line 2 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/XYZ/app/cache/dev/assetic_compassRm5H7y.css:
    This selector doesn't have any properties and will not be rendered.
    WARNING on line 3 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/XYZ/app/cache/dev/assetic_compassRm5H7y.css:
    This selector doesn't have any properties and will not be rendered.


    Output:
    error /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/XYZ/app/cache/dev/assetic_compassRm5H7y.css (Line 5: Invalid CSS after "'lg'": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";")
    Compilation failed in 1 files.


    Input:
    /*! lightgallery - v1.2.21 - 2016-06-28
    * http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/
    * Copyright (c) 2016 Sachin N; Licensed Apache 2.0 */
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'lg';
    src: url("../fonts/lg.eot?n1z373");
    src: url("../fonts/lg.eot?#iefixn1z373") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/lg.woff?n1z373") format("woff"), url("../fonts/lg.ttf?n1z373") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/lg.svg?n1z373#lg") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }
    [...]
```

If I just rename the CSS file to SCSS it works. I don't know why compass has a problem processing the file when I send it as CSS to assetic.

Besindes this behaviour assetic shouldn't send the CSS file to compass anyway.
What did I do wrong?